# Could $ f $ be differentiable at $ x = 0 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I want to solve the following question:

Let $  f(x) $ be a function such that $ f(\frac{1}{n})=\frac{(-1)^n}{n}, \forall n \in \mathbb{N} $. Could $ f $ be differentiable at $ x = 0 $.

When I try to imagine it, I see that if $ f(x) $ were differentiable at $ x = 0 $, then it would have a tangent line to $ x = 0 $. But $ f $ varies between positive and negative as it approaches $ 0 $.

Therefore, I tried to suppose, to the contrary, that $ f(x) $ is differentiable at $ x = 0 $. Therefore, for $ \epsilon = \frac{1}{2} $, there exists a $ \delta > 0 $ such that for all $  h$, if $ 0 <  h < \delta $, then $ \left|\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}\right| < \epsilon $, and now I want to find an $ x $ between $ 0 $ and $ \delta $ that doesn't satisfy this condition, but I'm stuck. Could you please give me a $ \textbf{hint} $?

This is not homework, just an interesting question I found on an exam from a few years ago.

Comment: Try evaluating the limit along the sequence $h_n = ( 1/(2n) )_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$, then again along the sequence $h_n = (1/(2n+1))_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$.  Do you get the same thing both times?

Comment: It's also worth noting that, if $f$ is differentiable at zero, it must be true it is continuous at zero, so you know $f(0)=0$. That helps in calculating the difference quotients. Then follow Henderson's hint

Comment: Hint: The limits of $\frac{f(\tfrac{1}{2n})}{\tfrac{1}{2n}}$ and $\frac{f(\tfrac{1}{2n+1})}{\tfrac{1}{2n+1}}$ when $n \to \infty$ are different.

Comment: "For $\epsilon=\cdots$ there is $\delta=\cdots$" type thinking is not as useful if you don't have a clear idea of what you're going to do. Try using more concrete information (the explicit values $f(1/n)$)

Answer (score 5):

> **Theorem:** If $\lim_{x \to a} F(x) = L$ and $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is any sequence with the property that $\lim_{n\to\infty} x_n = a$, then
> $$ \lim_{n\to\infty} F(x_n) = L. $$

The first application of this theorem implies that the only reasonable value for $f(0)$ is zero.  Specifically, if $f$ is differentiable, then it must also be continuous.  But continuity implies that
$$ f(0) = \lim_{x\to 0} f(x) \overset{(\ast)}{=} \lim_{n\to\infty} f\left( \frac{1}{n} \right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{n} = 0, $$
where equality at ($\ast$) follows from the Theorem.

Now apply the theorem to the function
$$ F(h) = \frac{f(0+h) - f(0)}{h}. $$
If $f$ is differentiable, the $\lim_{h\to 0} F(h) = f'(0)$.  This implies that if $f$ is differentiable, then taking $h$ to zero along any sequence going to zero should give the same result (by the Theorem at the top of this answer).  To see that $f$ is not differentiable, it is sufficient to take the limit along two different sequences and get different results.

First, take the limit along the reciprocals of the even integers:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} F\left( \frac{1}{2n} \right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f\left( 0 + \frac{1}{2n}\right) - f(0)}{\frac{1}{2n}} =  \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ \frac{1}{2n} - 0}{\frac{1}{2n}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{2n}{2n} = 1.
$$
Now taking the limit along the reciprocals of the odd integers:
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty} F\left( \frac{1}{2n+1} \right) = \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{f\left( 0 + \frac{1}{2n+1}\right) - f(0)}{\frac{1}{2n+1}} =  \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{ \frac{-1}{2n+1} - 0}{\frac{1}{2n+1}} = \lim_{n\to\infty}  \frac{2n+1}{-(2n+1)} = -1.
$$
The limits disagree, hence $\lim_{h\to 0} F(h)$ does not exist.  Therefore $f$ is not differentiable.